# How to disable new popular post notification?

Tags: google-plus

Can someone tell me how to disable the new popular post notification on Google+?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your notifications on the left menu, click on the 3 dot menu on any of those notifications and click the second option (it's in Spanish in my picture so I cannot provide an example in English).

[image]